# Gaebar and Bulkloader Exporting Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bulkloader

I am trying to find a way that I can download my whole datastore into a file and upload it back to datastore not to lose information. So I have made some research about it and found that there are two existing ways to do this.

1. Gaebar which is another application.
2. The Bulkloader of app engine itself.

The data that I am going to export is very large. So which one should I use?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the App Engine bulk loader as it is the official tool. It works great for me and it's easy to just make a full backup.

Gaebar was created in 2008 and the App Engine bulk loader wasn't available at that time, as documented by the [Revision History](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/revision_history.html):

> **May 2009**
> A bulk data downloader has been added to appcfg.py, similar to the bulk data uploader.
>
> **February 2010**
> The bulk loader tools can now download all entities of all kinds.

I never used Gaebar, but I think it was mostly a workaround to App Engine's lack of a backup tool.